# Graph Theory- Visting a vertex

Tags: graph-theory

In the complete graph $K_{9}$ choose 2 vertices and call them A and B . Count the number of simple paths (Paths that don't revisit a vertex) between A and B

Don't know how to start :/

Comment: Think about how to _characterise_ a path: If you were to describe a specific such path to another person, what would be a good way to do it? Giving names to all the other vertices is a good place to start. Once you have such a system that works, you can start to think about how many descriptions there are within that system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 7 vertices other than $A$ and $B$ in the graph. So, if you want to count the number of paths of length $m+1$ ($1 \le m+1 \le 8$) between $A$ and $B$, you must choose $m$ vertices from those 7 vertices and the arrange them in an order (so you will have a path starting at $A$, going through those $m$ vertices in that specific order and ending at $B$), which is possible in ${7 \choose m}m!$ . So the number of paths between $A$ and $B$ is : $\sum_0^7{{7 \choose m}m!}$ .